# How are 'change' events handled in backbone models?

Tags: backbone.js, model, meteor

I'm trying to build a model that dynamically updates Session variables in a Meteor project. I know that plain JSON should not be stored within backbone models, so I have a Special model set up like so:

```
initialize : function () {
    // Log the changed properties
    this.on('change', function (model, options) {
        for ( var i in options.changes)
            this.display(i);
        Session.set('NewSpecial', model);
    });
},
//Attributes
defaults: {
    "Product" : null,
    "ShortDescription" : null,
    "Category" : "food",
    "Price" : new PriceModel,
    "Date" : new DateModel,
    "Uses" : 0,
    "Tags" : [],
    "Contributor" : null
},
```

With "Price" and "Date" being stored in their own models:

```
//Price model for use within Special
var PriceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        "Regular" : null,
        "Special" : null,
        "PercentOff" : null
    }
});

//Date model for use within Special
var DateModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        "StartTime" : null,
        "EndTime" : null,
        "HumanTimeRange" : null
    }
});
```

As shown, when the attributes of the Special model change, it should call display for the attribute that changed, and then set the Session var to the model. If my DateModel or PriceModel change however, it doesn't appear to trigger a change event on the Special model. Should each "DateModel" and "PriceModel" have their own `this.on('change', ...)` methods that call `Special.set(attribute, thisModel)` methods? Or is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple problems.

First of all, your `defaults`:

```
defaults: {
    "Product" : null,
    "ShortDescription" : null,
    "Category" : "food",
    "Price" : new PriceModel,
    "Date" : new DateModel,
    "Uses" : 0,
    "Tags" : [],
    "Contributor" : null
}
```

That will end up with one `PriceModel`, one `DateModel`, and one tags array being shared by all instances of that model. A [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) object is shallow copied and merged into the model's attributes, none of the values in `defaults` are cloned or duplicated, they're just copied over as-is. If you want distinced `Price`, `Date`, and `Tags` values then use a function for `defaults`:

```
defaults: function() {
    return {
        "Product" : null,
        "ShortDescription" : null,
        "Category" : "food",
        "Price" : new PriceModel,
        "Date" : new DateModel,
        "Uses" : 0,
        "Tags" : [],
        "Contributor" : null
    };
}
```

The second problem is that [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) has a fairly simplistic view of what *change* means. If you have a look at the [source for `set`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L262), you'll see this:

```
// If the new and previous value differ, record the change.  If not,
// then remove changes for this attribute.
if (!_.isEqual(prev[attr], val) || (_.has(now, attr) !== _.has(prev, attr))) {
  this.changed[attr] = val;
  if (!silent) this._pending[attr] = true;
} else {
  delete this.changed[attr];
  delete this._pending[attr];
  if (!changing) delete this._changes[attr];
}
```

The [`_.isEqual`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) won't recognize that something has changed inside your `Price` or `Date` or that you've added or removed something from `Tags`. If you do things like this:

```
p = new PriceModel(...);
m.set('Price', p)
```

then `m` will noticed that `Price` has changed but if you:

```
p = m.get('Price');
p.set(...);
m.set('Price', p);
```

then `m` won't recognize that `Price` has changed; your model won't automatically bind to events on `Price` so it won't notice the `p.set(...)` call and it won't recognize `m.set('Price', p)` as a change since that's little more than a fancy way of saying `p = p`.

You can solve part of this *change* problem by not giving `set` a `Tags` array that came from `get`; make a copy, change the copy, and then hand the updated copy to `set`. The half can be handled by binding to `"change"` events on the contained `Price` and `Date` models and forwarding them similar to how collections do it, something like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.attributes.Price.on(
        'all',
        function(ev, model, opts) { this.trigger(ev, model, opts) },
        this
    );
    //...
}
```

You'd want to provide your own `set` implementation in case someone did a `set('Price', some_new_object)` and you need to rebind your forwarder.