# updating Backbone submodels after fetch/save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my Backbone application I have a model consisting of a couple of sub-models as parameters.

I define it so:

```
app.Models.Account = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize : function( ) {
        this.set( { 
                info     : new app.Models.Info(),
                logins   : new app.Collections.Logins(),
                billing  : new app.Models.Billing(),
            } );
    }

});
```

The problem is when fetching and saving. When I fetch for example the JSON response includes 
an object for `info`, an array for `logins` and an object for `billing`. Backbone automatically assigns them as normal parameters which means the sub-models are overridden with a simple object.

My current solution is to override the `fetch` method for the model like so:

```
    fetch: function( options ) {
      options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
      var model = this;
      var success = options.success;
      options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
        resp = model.parse( resp, xhr );

        model.get('info').set(resp.info);

        model.get('logins').reset(resp.logins);

        model.get('billing').set(resp.billing);

        if (success) success(model, resp);
      };

      options.error = Backbone.wrapError(options.error, model, options);
      return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
    }
```

however this is only for fetch. And since the updated status of the model created is returned when calling the `save()` method I have to also override the `save()` method.

Are there any good approaches to solve this issue?

Perhaps overriding the `set()` method could work, however I fear that would mean that I would be beginning to go astray from the Backbone codebase.

I also thought about using the parse method like so

```
    parse : function ( response ) {
        this.model.get('info').set(response.info);
        response.info = this.model.get('info');

        this.model.get('logins').reset(response.logins);
        response.logins = this.model.get('logins')

        this.model.get('billing').set(response.billing);
        response.billing = this.model.get('billing');

        return response;
    }
```

which would create a reference to the already updated sub model.

Comment: One possible caveat with things like `this.model.get('info').set(response.info); response.info = this.model.get('info');` is that `x = m.get('p'); x.set(...); m.set('p', x)` won't trigger a `"change"` event (see the second half of http://stackoverflow.com/a/13369672/479863), I'm not sure if this will be an issue with your `parse` though.

Comment: I have to test how that would work if I have events bound to the submodels. Either way I can live without having change events on the parent model since It's mostly used to structure everything together and make the ajax requests ( using backbone sync ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally use `parse` for sub-models, as in your second example (though note that you need to return `response` at the end). I think this is conceptually accurate, as `parse` is the appropriate place for transforming the server-side representation into a client-side one. I believe this should work for `save` as well, though I haven't tested it, since `parse` is called on the save response too.

In my experience, overriding `set` is nothing but trouble - it tends to have unintended side-effects, and is better avoided.

Comment: `set` is also surprisingly complicated so, if you do override it, you'll usually want to just tweak things and punt to the standard `set`.