# waiting till an on change handler is complete before saving model

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I have a User model(Backbone.js) and I want to update its settings attribute and then save it to the server. Settings is in JSON format, and the way I have it set up is that settings is the string version and settingsJSON is the object version. I bind functions to the change event of each so that when one changes, it updates the other.

The problem I am having, is that the save method is running before the changed handler is finished running. Is there any way i could ensure that all event handlers for that model are complete or something like that?

how I'm calling it:

```
currentUser.get('settingsJSON').apps = appsEnabled;
currentUser.save();
```

My event handlers:

```
Initialize: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.on("change:settingsJSON", function(model){
        model.set({settings: JSON.stringify(model.get('settingsJSON'))});
    });

    this.on("change:settings", function(model){
        model.set({settingsJSON: JSON.parse(model.get('settings'))});
    });
}
```

@fencliff:

The change event is firing when I run this and works properly, I had it print the new settings string to the console.

Are you sure that they are called synchronously? I added `console.log('changed')` to the end of the `.on(change)` and put `console.log('saved')` directly after `currentUser.save()` and every time the console read:

```
saved
changed
```

For now I have just made it so that I stringily the JSON and save it to settings directly before I save and that works fine.

Comment: I'm *relatively* sure that the events are fired synchronously, and also that `model.get('settingsJSON').apps = true` will **not** trigger any events. But I've been wrong twice in this thread already, so what do I know. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T7jKg/ . Can you fork it and show what's going on in your code?

Comment: @fencliff I think what must have been happening was that change was being fired by something else, possible the .save(). Not totally sure. I will probably revisit this later to try to get it working how i want it, but for now my fix will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone events are executed synchronously. That means that unless you (or some library) has overridden some part of the event handling, the change handlers will have processed as soon as you execute the next line of code.

In you code example there is another problem. When you call

```
user.get('settingsJSON').apps = appsEnabled;
```

The `change` event will **not** fire, because the value of `settingsJSON` has not been changed, merely the contents of the object were modified. The `model.attributes.settingsJSON` is still the same object as before.

The events are fired only when you call `set` on the property, and the new value is a **different** object. For example:

```
user.set('settingsJSON', _.extend({}, user.get('settingsJSON'), {apps:appsEnabled});
```

Another problem, it would seem, is that your event handlers, if triggered, would cause the `change` event being fired twice for the property which was first set:

```
this.on("change:settingsJSON", function(model){
    //-> changes settings, and set triggers change
    model.set({settings: JSON.stringify(model.get('settingsJSON'))});
});

this.on("change:settings", function(model){
    //-> changes settingsJSON, and set triggers change
    model.set({settingsJSON: JSON.parse(model.get('settings'))});
});
```

To solve that issue, call `set` with `{silent:true}` or modify the `model.attributes` hash directly.

**Edited** with corrections by @muistooshort.

**Edited** again with further corrections

Comment: Are you sure those two `set` calls will trigger `"change"` events?

Comment: @muistooshort, I don't see why they wouldn't, but then again I'm pretty drunk and on my phone so can't test. Why wouldn't they?

Comment: They won't because `set` essentially uses `==` to skip setting attributes that haven't changed adding a new property to an object won't change its reference value. You'd need to hand `set` something more like `_.extend({}, user.get('settingsJSON'), { apps: appsEnabled })` to force the production of a new object so that you can get past the simple-minded equality filter.

Comment: More details on this particular `set` trap: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13369672/479863 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11662381/479863

Comment: @fencliff see my edits. I did change them to {silent: true} though, good heads up. mu is too short i will look at those

Comment: @muistooshort, ah, you're correct. I thought you meant the circular reference `set`s in the last example. Corrected my answer with fixed code. Thanks!

Comment: @muistooshort, it seems that the `==` comparison also prevents the infinite loop from happening. The `change` event is fired one extra time for the property whose set originally triggered the changes, but after that `old == new`, so it will not trigger any further. I swear I wasn't even drunk when I wrote the original answer!